# Convert anonymous inner class to Java 8 lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Sonar static code analysis tells me this is a code smell and should be converted to a lamdba.

```
 public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
               .allowedOrigins("*")
               .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

I've tried various approaches with no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried and what is/are the problem(s) you have encountered?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `WebMvcConfigurer` is a functional interface, the method can be changed to the following:

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
     return registry -> registry.addMapping("/**")
                                .allowedOrigins("*")
                                .allowedMethods("*");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob. This produced: [ERROR]  incompatible types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer is not a functional interface
    no abstract method found in interface org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer

Comment: Yep, this only works if `WebMvcConfigurer` is a functional interface, which it apparently isn't.  The only other option is to create your own functional interface that extends `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Comment: This may be a bug in sonar. Looking at WebMvcConfigurer, all of its methods are `default`. It could be that sonar thinks it's a functional interface because it doesn't have _more_ than one abstract method; it should instead be checking that it had exactly one.